# Can I omit Advanced Missions in Star Fleet Battles?

Tags: expansions, star-fleet-battles

Do I still need the Advanced Missions box, if I have got the Advanced Missions countersheet, the accompanying SSD book, the Master Rulebook and Module G3?

Is there anything else in there I wouldn't get that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found out that I won't miss anything ruleswise, but I will have neither the (sometimes necessary) ship descriptions (but those can also be found in the Master Starship books for the specific races/factions) nor the scenarios.